# Apache as proxy to use same URL with subroutes for different apps

Tags: apache, docker, proxy, reverse-proxy

I am trying to set up an Apache2 web server as a proxy to redirect requests to different apps running on the server in separate Docker containers.

All requests going to route *http://my_url.com/App2* should be directed to App2 running at *localhost:8002*.
All other requests to *http://my_url.com* should be redirected to App1 running on *localhost:8001*.

I used the following Apache configuration file:

```
VirtualHost my_url.com/:80>
    ServerName my_url.com
    ServerAlias www.my_url.com
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /App2/ http://localhost:8002/
    ProxyPassReverse /App2/ http://localhost:8002/

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8001/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8001/
</VirtualHost>
```

If I try to access App2, it initially redirects to the correct Docker container. However, the Problem is now that if App2 does a redirect to for example the */login* route, the subroute */App2/* gets lost and Apache tries  to find */login* in App1 container.

What should happen is: 
App2 wants to redirect to */login* and makes the browser access *my_url.com/App2/login* and not *my_url.com/login*.

Is this achievable with just Apache configurations or do I need to change the redirects in App2 Docker container?

Comment: Can you check (using `curl -v`, or browser developer console) what exactly is the content of `Location` header when the redirect is sent back from your app?

Comment: After accessing: http://my_url.com/App2 the response header contains: "Location: http://my_url.com/login" which should be  "Location: http://my_url.com/App2/login" in order to work.

Comment: Can you 1) add `127.0.0.1 my_url.com` to apache server's `/etc/hosts` file 2) change all ProxyPass rules to use real hostname

Comment: you mean replace the "http://localhost" in the ProxyPass rules by "my_url.com"?

Comment: yes try that please

Comment: the hosts file  contains already the line "127.0.0.1 localhost" and this is what I referred to originally. adding the url as you mentioned results in the same issue.

Comment: `ProxyPassReverse` line in your configuration should take care of proper rewriting of `Location:` header in your response, but in order to do so the value of the header needs to match the value in your apache configuration. If value in your response is `http://my_url.com/login`, then it will not work because port number is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the line `ProxyPreserveHost On`. This resulted in Apache adding the header field:

```
X-Forwarded-Host: 'my_url.com'
```

for every request.
Thats why the ProxyPassReverse:

```
ProxyPassReverse /App2/ http://localhost:8002/
```

didn't work since it is only rewriting requests from `http://localhost:8002/`.

Setting `ProxyPreserveHost Off` (which is also the default) solved the issue for me.